# How many transactions with equal priority can be imported in one block?

Tags: transactions, aura

I've been having the problem of transactions not being imported at the same block in a local network. When submitting one transaction from three nodes in a local network at the same time, those transactions only get imported across three blocks. I've ensured that the transactions have not excluded the transaction pool limits, yet at each block, only one transaction gets imported.

A more detailed description of the scenario:

1. Launch a local network of three nodes with offchain workers that submit an unsigned transaction with maximum priority and different `provides` tags at each block
2. One transaction gets taken from the `ready` pool, other two txs get pruned & revalidated (even though the network is idling)
3. On the next block, **two** transactions from **the next node** get imported, the other four (two from the previous block, two from this block) stay in the pool, get revalidated
4. Repeat

Could it be an issue of Aura (all three nodes are validators), an issue of priority, an issue of unsigned transactions, or something else? Are there any restrictions on how many transactions (given that they satisfy the limits) can be imported in a block? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any `InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources`, or `InvalidTransaction::Stale` or similar in your logs?

Comment: Nope, I'm not getting those errors. It seems that those transactions undergo a normal process of revalidation - they are pruned from the block & then reprocessed in the next block (one by one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was much simpler than I imagined. In my `ValidateUnsigned`, I added a check to restrict the transactions from `TransactionSource::External`, and completely forgot that the transactions that are gossiped get the `External` transaction source.
The solution was to enable debug logs for `sc_service`, see the error and remove that check.